# Apache installation errors "only one usage of each socket address <protocol/network address/port "

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, port

I get an error message when I try to run httpd.exe.

I have tried to resolve port conflicts - I uninstalled skypee, SQL Server Management studio and SQL Server Business Intelligence development studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check what ports your firewall and antivirus software uses and/or blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You have another software running at port 8080.

To know which is it, open cmd as admin, write `netstat -a -b` and look for it.

Comment: i wrote -a -b on cmd and its showing me {logging server.exe}

Comment: Fine. Now type `dir server.exe /s` and let it find server.exe for you ;-)

Comment: Thank you dear Santeador. i wrote dir server.exe /s on CMD n its showing me  Volume in  drive C is Acer, Volume serial number is 186F-49D4, File not found.what should i do?

Comment: My bad. Try `dir server.* /s`

Comment: I have changed the port number on httpd.conf into "Listen 80", When i tried to run on CMD its working. The problem is its not working on browser. i was trying to test it on Browser..it says Error 403, the server is refusing the request.what is the solution for that, Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you tipping `http://127.0.0.1`?

Comment: it brings Error 403 when i try to test it on the browser

Comment: yes i did type localhost and 127.0.0.1....my CMD looks fine but the problem is on the browse part

Comment: Did you set up any Virtual Host for Apache?

Comment: i have no idea about Virtual host.Do i have to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find them in Windows... a vhost is what Apache server share. If it is still pointing to *:8080 you cannot reach it...

Comment: Maybe this can help you undertanding vhosts: http://laternastudio.com/blog/setting-up-an-apache-2-2-21-virtual-host-windows